# Cannot publish to reserved topic using AWS IoT SDK

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, iot

I am currently using the javascript AWS Iot SDK. Adapting the example provided [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-js/blob/master/examples/browser/temperature-monitor/index.js), I have been able to register with my thingShadow, and I am trying to publish an update after registration. However, when I do, I get the following error message:

```
cannot publish to reserved topic '$aws/things/<thingName>/shadow/update'
```

I understand the '$' indicates that this is a reserved topic, but Amazon's documentation (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/topics.html)
states that publish and subscribe operations are allowed for this reserved topic. If that is the case, I am not sure why my attempt to publish is resulting in an error. This snippet demonstrates how I attempt to publish in my connection callback:

```
shadows.register(<thingName>, {
    persistentSubscribe: true
}, () => {
    shadows.publish('$aws/things/<thingName>/shadow/update', <message>);
});
```

Comment: At the risk of asking a ridiculous question, you're not literally using the characters `<thingName>` in the literal string you've shown at `shadows.publish('$aws/things/<thingName>/shadow/update', <message>);`... right?  There's an actual valid thing name here?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Haha, fair question. Yes, I am currently using a valid thingName and message in those strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see that you are using the [thing shadow class](https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-js#thing-shadows) of the SDK to publish on a reserved topic. By looking at the source code of the SDK, I see that [it is not possible to publish on a reserved topic](https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-js/blob/master/thing/index.js#L705) using this type of client, since all operations on reserved topics are conducted by `.register()` and `.update()`.

You can however publish on [these reserved topics](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/topics.html#reserved-topics) by using the [device class](https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-js#device-class).